# Good quality espresso / cappuccino maker that doesn't leak or break within 18 months of use

Tags: coffee-machines

I have been buying de Longhi coffee machines for a while now and they seem to be getting worse.  I started on a Delonghi EC152 which was low cost and pretty reliable.  Then when my 2nd one died, I tried to order a replacement but it had been discontinued and so equivalent model was a EC146.B which was really poor.  As luck would have it, or so I thought, I received another de Longhi as a present, an EC 270.  But this leaks like crazy after only a few weeks.  If you fiddle with the valve on the  water vessel it stops leaking for a few  hours.

So I would like to buy a coffee maker which doesn't leak and which will last.

Willing to spend a reasonable amount to get something that will last.

I am looking for a home use machine for say 1-2 cups per day.  Our cooker is an electric hob - so not sure the stove types would work.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Honestly Bialetti stovetop percolators are some of the most reliable coffee makers I've used. Not *quite* espresso, but pretty dang close.

Comment: What is your usage like -- 1 cup per day personal-use, or 100 cups per day office/commercial? On a similar note, what kind of machine are you looking for? Have you seen similar complaints on review sites for the products you've used? Please clarify or narrow your question, or this will surely end in a speculative bedlam of opinions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd thoroughly recommend the Rancilio Siliva  at http://www.ranciliogroup.com/1-Rancilio-Homeline--Silvia

I moved up to this machine after 2 gaggias, and another cheaper machine. This is far superior. Fully manual but rock solid build quality, consistent. Wonderful coffee

Answer (score 3):

[image: Vesuviana espresso maker image from ubbcentral.com]

I think I put a new gasket in the Vesuviana once, but I find it more of a pain to clean than I like. Still, gotta be pushing 50 years old, pretty reliable.

Also a stovetop device, but purported espresso. Espresso snobs may say it's not real espresso.

For cappuccino there are similar stovetop devices to make steam with.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I haven't changed coffee machine.  I found that after using various Delonghi machines for a while, the pump would be working hard but not get much pressure.   I started doing a de-scale monthly and that has extended the lifetime of the unit ... well indefinitely so far.

I use: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BS5SY2C/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
but others would do the job.